# How do I connect bluez-alsa to an audio device?

Tags: bluetooth

How do I connect bluez-alsa to an audio device?

1. It works with pulseaudio so I know it works, generally speaking.
2. I need it to work with bluez-alsa so that I can use it with WINE to play video games with a bluetooth headset. :-)
3. bluez-alsa is installed already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was under the impression that ALSA didn't support Bluez5 and I didn't gather from your other post that you're running Bluez4. So you may have some problems or other work to do. That being said I'll give you the general idea of using alsa and Bluez4.

1. Go through your usual pairing and get the device's address or use bluetoothctl/hcitool:

   ```
   $ hcitool scan
   Scanning ...
       XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  NAMEOFHEADSET

   $ bluez-simple-agent XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   ```
2. Next edit /etc/asound.conf (system-wide) or ~/asound.conf (userlevel)

   ```
   pcm.btheadset {
   type plug
    slave {
      pcm {
          type bluetooth
          device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          profile "auto"
      }
    }
    hint {
      show on
      description "BT Headset"
    }
   }
   ctl.btheadset {
     type bluetooth
   }
   ```

If this gives you any trouble you can try changing the first line to `pcm.!default {` which will force this to be the default audio device.

3. Reload alsa so that it picks up the changes in asound.conf and check that the device is added.

   ```
   $ sudo alsa reload
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils restart
   $ aplay -L
   ```
4. Test out your sound!

As a closing thought here, did you decide to switch to alsa directly because you've had problems with specific wine applications? Normally the Pulseaudio-alsa is good enough for most games etc. that you'd run in wine and unfortunately the entire Linux audio stack is what keeps a lot of game developers away from Linux entirely so keep that in mind too.

Comment: I've not had a chance to test this yet. I've been pretty busy.